# Azure Data Factory merge 2 csv files with different schema

Tags: merge, azure-data-factory

I am trying to merge the 2 csv files(in Azure data factory) which has different schema. Below is the scenario

CSV 1: 15 columns -> say 5 dimensions and 10 metrices(x1, x2,...x10)
CSV 2: 15 columns -> 5 dimensions(same as above) and 10 metrices(different from above, y1, y2...y10)
So my schema is different. Now I have to merge both CSV files so that only 5 dimensions comes with all 20 metrices.

I tried with Data Transformation using Select operation. That is giving me 2 rows in the merged file. One row with first 5 dimensions and 10 metrices and second row with next 5 dimensions and 10 metrices, which is incorrect as I am looking only for one row with 5 dimensions and all 20 metrics(x1,x2...x10, y1,y2...y10)

Any help is much appreciated on this issue

Comment: "Data Transformation" - do you mean Data Flow? You should be able to JOIN the two CSV files (on those five columns) and then SELECT just the columns you want to output.

Comment: @JoelCochran..Thank you for the response. I tried this approach but the issue is matching column doesn't have the matching data values in 5 dimensions. so join is not working for me. so what would you suggest. Please kindly provide your inputs. Thanks

Comment: If there is no matching data in the 5 dimensions, wondering what will be the data values in the dimension columns after merge as you are expecting only single row. Can you share your expected output? and If possible please share sample input data as well.

Comment: If they don't match, then they won't JOIN. Are you just trying to get the full list of all these 5 columns from source A and all the five columns from source B? If so, SELECT the 5 columns from each source, then use a UNION to create a single list of all rows.

Comment: @JoelCochran...thanks for your response. I got clarity from business and the common columns have common data so my Join worked and able to get the final output file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @sac for the update and thank you @Joel Cochran, for the suggestion. Posting it as an answer to help other community members.

1. Use `Join` transformation and Join type as **[Inner join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join#inner-join-example)**. Use Key columns or common columns (dimension columns) from 2 Input files as your Join condition. This will output all columns from file1 and file2.
2. Use `Select` transformation to get the required **[select list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-select)** from the join output.

Refer below process for implementation:

**(i)** Join 2 source files, with inner join and key columns in the join condition.

[image]

**(ii)**    Output of Join transformation will list all the columns from source1 and all columns from source2 (includes duplicate key columns from both source files).

[image]

**(iii)**   Use select transformation and remove duplicate (or not required in select list) columns from the Join output.

[image]

**(iv)**    Output of Select transformation.

[image]